# How do I set startup/ home page to a desired website?

Tags: firefox

How do I set up the start up page to the desired website?  Automatically goes to Google Search. Not sure how to adjust.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu's default web browser is Firefox, you can edit the home page by going into the Edit menu, then selecting preferences, then using this dialog box:

[image]

From there you can click the "Use current page" button to set your home page to whatever page you are on, or just type the url in the field.

See also:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20set%20the%20home%20page